# Задача для школьника

Tags: php, sql

Помогите сделать норм запрос. Ошибка:

> `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2история' (sol) VALUES ('3')' at line 1`

```
$name = "$inputName" . "$history";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$name' (sol) VALUES ('$inputValue')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, имя таблицы нельзя в кавычках писать. Допускаются апострофы. Попробуйте